# Get a substring with "text+space+number" and trim the rest

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

How can you write a function/regex that gives you the first block of chars + the first numbers not separated by a space and omit the rest?
Here are some examples of what the result should look like given different strings ("input" -> "result"):

```
"abc 1" -> "abc 1"
"abc def 1" -> "abc def 1"
"abc-def 1" -> "abc-def 1"
"abc 1b" -> "abc 1"
"abc 11 b3" -> "abc 11"
"abc 11 3" -> "abc 11"
"abc 11b" -> "abc 11"
```

Comment: maybe this `[a-zA-Z]* \d*`. or this `\S* \d*`

Comment: I just checked it but I went with the regex for the readability, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (words comprise a-z -)

```
Match match = Regex.Match(value, @"^([A-Za-z-]+) (\d+)");
if (match.Success)
{
    var word = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var num  = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Comment: You didn't match the second line. Should actually be `^([A-Za-z- ]+) (\d+)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the LINQ solution by using `TakeWhile` and `SkipWhile` methods. (I tested all your entries and it works):

```
string str = "abc 11 3";
var result = string.Concat(string.Join("", str.TakeWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c))),
             string.Join("", str.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)));
```

Just don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` to your `using` directive first.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] Value = new string[] {
 "abc 1",
"abc def 1",
"abc-def 1",
"abc 1b",
"abc 11 b3",
"abc 11 3",
"abc 11b"
            };


            foreach (string value in Value)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(value, @"^([A-Za-z-]+) (\d+)");
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    var word = match.Groups[1].Value;
                    var num = match.Groups[2].Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(word + " " + num);
                }
            }

        }
    }


//abc 1
//abc-def 1
//abc 1
//abc 11
//abc 11
//abc 11
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

`^(.*)[0-9]`